# Amazon CloudFront Intermittent "Failed to contact the origin"

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, dns, amazon-cloudfront, elastic-load-balancer

We started seeing this issue about 2 hours ago. It's happening very randomly. For example, if you copy and paste this URL for the image into browser, the chance of it not showing up for me is about 20%.

https://d1jbmqjs327xbn.cloudfront.net/_pa/spaces-developer.pxand/assets/images/apps/pos/pos-login-bg.jpg

Even after the browser able to load the image, it may not load if you do a hard refresh. Then it will eventually doing hard refresh 2-3 more times.

This seems like a networking issue on AWS side.

Another thing I saw is that 3 of my domains randomly became unreachable for a few minutes (I tested with ping) and then they eventually become reachable again without making any change on my side.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue today (Sep 20, 2017)? This is causing an issue for 10+ sites/apps I manage and I'm not quite sure how to solve this issue. Amazon is also not getting back to me on this.

Comment: Seems like it works now after I complained on every social networks. I guess I should have started with that 2 hours ago.

Comment: We're they `.io` domains, perhaps?  It seems `.io` was having an outage around the time of your post.

Comment: Yes, they are .io domains. Where can I check for outage information for specific domain suffix?

Comment: There was a post today on [AWS Status](https://status.aws.amazon.com) and it appeared in [Personal Health Dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/phd/) as well.  There was also [chatter at Y Combinator](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15293811&source=techstories.org).